# Can you not combine a variable with a string to look up another variable?

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

I have a script that I'm creating to create new users and add publickeys when I boot up a new node. However I'm running into issues when trying to pull from (user)_PUBLIC_KEYS array.

```
#!/bin/sh

USERS=(
    User1
    User2
)
User1_PUBLIC_KEYS=(
    "ssh-rsa ..."
    "ssh-rsa ..."
)

User2_PUBLIC_KEYS=(
    "ssh-rsa ..."
)

for user in "${USERS}"; do
    USERNAME="${user}"
    ...
    # Add provided public keys
    for key in "${USER}_PUBLIC_KEYS[@]"; do
        echo "${key}" >> "${home_directory}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    done
    ...
done
```

I've even tried testing

```
user+="_PUBLIC_KEYS[@]"
    # Add provided public keys
    for key in "${user}"; do
        echo "${key}"
    done
```

This results in

```
User1
User1_PUBLIC_KEYS[@]
User2
User2_PUBLIC_KEYS[@]
```

Comment: The syntax `USER=(....)` is not even valid in POSIX shell. If you want to use arrays, use bash, zsh or ksh.

Comment: In other words, arrays are not available using `#!/bin/sh` as the interpreter at the top of your script. They would be if you used `#!/bin/bash` or another modern shell like `ksh` or `zsh`.

Comment: Okay, so even after changing I'm still getting the same problem. Is this just out of the scope using a shell script and I should be using something in perhaps python?